# Extract the last part of a row character

Tags: r, rows

I need to extract the last part of a row in  the data frame which it is in yellow

[image]

I want to remove this characters,thanks

Comment: Hello it's not clear whether you want to keep or remove yellow part (you use extract that means keep, and remove just after)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(c1 = str_remove(c1, '[A-Z].+'))
                   c1
1 \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)
2 \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)
3 \r\n\t\t\t\t(15:15 GMT)

df %>% mutate(c1 = str_remove(c1, '.*\\b'))
                    c1
1  \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)
2  \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)
3  \r\n\t\t\t\t(15:15 GMT)
```

Data used:

```
df
                               c1
1      Huesca \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)
2    Elche CF \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)
3 Read Madrid \r\n\t\t\t\t(15:15 GMT)
```

Comment: I think the OP means the opposite (see line below image)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your data you could use a simple string cutting function since the length of the last part is always the same (VISTANTE_2. Or you use pattern machting (VISITANTE_1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(rebus)
library(stringr)
# The pattern we are looking for
pattern <- SPACE %R% "\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\(" %R% optional(DGT) %R% DGT %R% ":" %R% DGT %R% DGT %R% SPACE %R% "GMT\\)" %R% END

df <- dplyr::tibble(VISITANTE = c("Huesca \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)","Elche CF \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)"))

df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(VISITANTE_1 = stringr::str_extract(VISITANTE, pattern),
                VISITANTE_2 = stringr::str_sub(VISITANTE, -18, -1))

  VISITANTE                          VISITANTE_1                VISITANTE_2               
  <chr>                              <chr>                      <chr>                     
1 "Huesca \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)"   " \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)" " \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)"
2 "Elche CF \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)" " \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)" " \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)"
```

If you prefer to have the result without the leading space/blank you have to remove "SPACE %R%" from the pattern or change -18 to -17 in the str_sub()

In case you are looking for the opposite (remove what you marked in yellow) here is a possible solution using the same packages:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(VISITANTE_1 = stringr::str_remove(VISITANTE, pattern),
                VISITANTE_2 = stringr::str_sub(VISITANTE, 1, nchar(VISITANTE) - 18))

  VISITANTE                          VISITANTE_1 VISITANTE_2
  <chr>                              <chr>       <chr>      
1 "Huesca \r\n\t\t\t\t(20:00 GMT)"   Huesca      Huesca     
2 "Elche CF \r\n\t\t\t\t(13:00 GMT)" Elche CF    Elche CF
```